# How to use LockScreen.SetImageUri to Set Windows Phone 8 Lock Screen Background

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage, lockscreen

I have an image in IsolatedStorage, and I would like to programmatically set it as the device lock screen background. My problem is that I cannot get the correct path required by `LockScreen.SetImageUri`. From referencing http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206968(v=vs.105).aspx it is evident that `"ms-appdata:///local/" is the required precursor for local images.

```
var schema = isAppResource ? "ms-appx:///" : "ms-appdata:///Local/";
var uri = new Uri(schema + filePathOfTheImage, UriKind.Absolute);
```

I have created a folder in my applications IsolatedStorage called `Pictures` in which jpg images are saved from the CameraCaptureTask. I have tried several ways to access images within this folder via the above scheme but I always receive an `ArgumentException` on the next line

```
Windows.Phone.System.UserProfile.LockScreen.SetImageUri(uri);
```

When debugging, however, I see that `uri = "ms-appdata:///Local/Pictures/WP_20130812_001.jpg"`, how is this not correct?

My implementation is as follows

```
private void recent_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{            
    capturedPicture = (sender as LongListSelector).SelectedItem as CapturedPicture;

    if (capturedPicture != null)
    {
        //filename is the name of the image in the IsolatedStorage folder named Pictures
        fileName = capturedPicture.FileName;
    }
}

void setAsLockScreenMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName)) 
    {
        //PictureRepository.IsolatedStoragePath is a string = "Pictures"                
        //LockHelper("isostore:/" + PictureRepository.IsolatedStoragePath + "/" + fileName, false);  //results in FileNotFoundException
        LockHelper(PictureRepository.IsolatedStoragePath + "/" + fileName, false);  //results in ArgumentException
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("You must select an image to set it as your lock screen.", "Notice", MessageBoxButton.OK);
        if (result == MessageBoxResult.OK)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
}

private async void LockHelper(string filePathOfTheImage, bool isAppResource)
{
try
{
    var isProvider = Windows.Phone.System.UserProfile.LockScreenManager.IsProvidedByCurrentApplication;
    if (!isProvider)
    {
        // If you're not the provider, this call will prompt the user for permission.
        // Calling RequestAccessAsync from a background agent is not allowed.
        var op = await Windows.Phone.System.UserProfile.LockScreenManager.RequestAccessAsync();

        // Only do further work if the access was granted.
        isProvider = op == Windows.Phone.System.UserProfile.LockScreenRequestResult.Granted;
    }

    if (isProvider)
    {
        // At this stage, the app is the active lock screen background provider.

        // The following code example shows the new URI schema.
        // ms-appdata points to the root of the local app data folder.
        // ms-appx points to the Local app install folder, to reference resources bundled in the XAP package.
        var schema = isAppResource ? "ms-appx:///" : "ms-appdata:///Local/";
        var uri = new Uri(schema + filePathOfTheImage, UriKind.Absolute);

        // Set the lock screen background image.
        Windows.Phone.System.UserProfile.LockScreen.SetImageUri(uri);

        // Get the URI of the lock screen background image.
        var currentImage = Windows.Phone.System.UserProfile.LockScreen.GetImageUri();
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("The new lock screen background image is set to {0}", currentImage.ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You said no, so I can't update your background.");
    }
}
catch (System.Exception ex)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
}
```

}

How might I modify `LockScreen.SetImageUri` to the proper expected uri?

Answer (score 1):

For setting lock screen images from the app, you might want to declare your app as lock screen provider. You can do that by modifying the WMAppManifest.xml file by adding the following tag:

```
<Extensions>
  <Extension ExtensionName="LockScreen_Background" ConsumerID="{111DFF24-AA15-4A96-8006-2BFF8122084F}" TaskID="_default" />
</Extensions>
```

Check to see if you have this tag in your manifest file.

Comment: To note, I placed my `<Extensions>..</Extensions>` under the closing `Token` tag like so
    `</Tokens>
    <Extensions>
      <Extension ExtensionName="LockScreen_Background" ConsumerID="{111DFF24-AA15-4A96-8006-2BFF8122084F}" TaskID="_default" />
    </Extensions>`

Answer (score 0):

I hope this could help you to address your issue.

If your app is already installed, make sure that it is an background image provider. If not then go to settings -> lock screen -> background and select your application from the list.

On the programmatic side:

**1. Declare the app’s intent in the application manifest file**
Edit WMAppManifest.xml with the XML editor, make sure the following extension is present:

```
<Extensions> <Extension ExtensionName="LockScreen_Background" ConsumerID="{111DFF24-AA15-4A96-8006-2BFF8122084F}" TaskID="_default" /> </Extensions>
```

**2. Write code to change the background image**
The following is an example of how you can write the code for setting the background.

```
private async void lockHelper(Uri backgroundImageUri, string backgroundAction)
        {
            try
            {
                //If you're not the provider, this call will prompt the user for permission. 
                //Calling RequestAccessAsync from a background agent is not allowed. 
                var op = await LockScreenManager.RequestAccessAsync();
                //Check the status to make sure we were given permission. 
                bool isProvider = LockScreenManager.IsProvidedByCurrentApplication; if (isProvider)
                {
                    //Do the update. 
                    Windows.Phone.System.UserProfile.LockScreen.SetImageUri(backgroundImageUri);
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("New current image set to {0}", backgroundImageUri.ToString());
                }
                else { MessageBox.Show("You said no, so I can't update your background."); }
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex) { System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }
        }
```

Regarding Uris, there are many options, but keep on mind:

To use an image that you shipped in your app, use ms-appx:///

```
Uri imageUri = new Uri("ms-appx:///background1.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute); LockScreen.SetImageUri(imageUri);
```

To use an image stored in the Local Folder, use ms-appdata:///local/shared/shellcontent
**Must be** in or below the /shared/shellcontent subfolder

```
Uri imageUri = new Uri("ms-appdata:///local/shared/shellcontent/background2.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute); LockScreen.SetImageUri(imageUri);
```

Comment: You could also check http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Dynamic_Lock_Screen_for_Windows_Phone_8 for a working sample